# Workaround for non equal hive queries

Tags: join, hadoop, mapreduce, left-join, hive

I try to rewrite follow query on hive

```
select 
    TFCT_CHARGE.SUBS_KEY, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.PRODUCT_KEY, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.CHARGE_NVAL, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.B_SUBS_KEY, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.DELETE_DT, 
    HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT.SEGMENT_KEY, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.EVENT_DT, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.DWH_SRC_TABLE_KEY
  from
TFCT_CHARGE LEFT OUTER JOIN HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT
ON (
TFCT_CHARGE.B_SUBS_KEY = HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT.SUBS_KEY and
TFCT_CHARGE.EVENT_DT >= HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT.EFF_DT    and
TFCT_CHARGE.EVENT_DT < HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT.EXP_DT     and
HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT.SEGMENT_TYPE_KEY = 1)
```

But there are non-equal query.
Could anybody hint me some workaround?
Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

To emulate a non-equi left outer join:

1. Create a copy of the left table with added serial row numbers
2. Do an inner join:
3. Left join by serial:

See my answer here for the code: [Hive: work around for non equi left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112355/hive-work-around-for-non-equi-left-join/25472664#25472664)

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy)))

```
select 
    TFCT_CHARGE.SUBS_KEY, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.PRODUCT_KEY, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.CHARGE_NVAL, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.B_SUBS_KEY, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.DELETE_DT, 
    HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT.SEGMENT_KEY, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.EVENT_DT, 
    TFCT_CHARGE.DWH_SRC_TABLE_KEY
  from
TFCT_CHARGE INNER JOIN HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT
ON (
TFCT_CHARGE.B_SUBS_KEY = HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT.SUBS_KEY
HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT.SEGMENT_TYPE_KEY = 1)
where
TFCT_CHARGE.EVENT_DT >= HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT.EFF_DT    and
TFCT_CHARGE.EVENT_DT < HFCT_SUBS_SEGMENT.EXP_DT     and
```

Comment: your answer does not account for the left outer join. you will be missing rows not in the inner join