# Hive: work around for non equi left join

Tags: join, hive, left-join

Hive does not support non equi joins: The common work around is to move the join condition to the where clause, which work fine when you want an inner join. but what about a left join?

Contrived example. Let say we have an orderLineItem table, and we need to join to a ProductPrice table that has a productID, price & a date range for which the price applies. We want to join to this where ProductID=ProductID & OrderDate between start and End date. If a productID or a valid date range do not match, I'd still want to see all orderLineItems.

This SQL fiddle is an example of how we'd do this in MSSQL:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fb877/7

**Problem**
If I apply the typical workaround, and move the non equi filter to the where clause, it becomes an inner join. In the case above, in the sql fiddle & below, I have a product ID that is not in the lookup.

**Question:**
Provided hive does not support non eqi-joins, How can a left non-eqi be achieved ?

[SQLFiddle Content]

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderLineItem(
  LineItemIDId int IDENTITY(1,1),
  OrderID int  NOT NULL,
  ProductID int NOT NULL,
  OrderDate Date
);


CREATE TABLE ProductPrice(
  ProductID int,
  Cost float,
  startDate  Date,
  EndDate  Date


);
```

loading The data & how we'd join in MSSQL:

```
--Old Price. Should be ignored
INSERT INTO ProductPrice(ProductID, COST,startDate,EndDate) VALUES  (1, 50,'12/1/2012','1/1/2013');
INSERT INTO ProductPrice(ProductID, COST,startDate,EndDate) VALUES (2, 55,'12/1/2012','1/1/2013');

--Price for Order 2. Should be applied to Order 1
INSERT INTO ProductPrice (ProductID, COST,startDate,EndDate) VALUES(1, 20,'12/1/2013','1/1/2014');
INSERT INTO ProductPrice (ProductID, COST,startDate,EndDate) VALUES(2, 25,'12/1/2013','1/1/2014');

--Price for Order 2. Should be applied to Order 2
INSERT INTO ProductPrice (ProductID, COST,startDate,EndDate) VALUES(1, 15,'1/2/2014','3/1/2014');
INSERT INTO ProductPrice (ProductID, COST,startDate,EndDate) VALUES(2, 20,'1/2/2014','3/1/2014');


--January 1st 2014 Order
INSERT INTO OrderLineItem(OrderID,ProductID,OrderDate) VALUES (1, 1,'1/1/2014') ;
INSERT INTO OrderLineItem(OrderID,ProductID,OrderDate) VALUES (1, 2,'1/1/2014');

--Feb 1st 2014 Order
INSERT INTO OrderLineItem(OrderID,ProductID,OrderDate) VALUES (2, 1,'2/1/2014');
INSERT INTO OrderLineItem (OrderID,ProductID,OrderDate) VALUES(2, 2,'2/1/2014');
INSERT INTO OrderLineItem (OrderID,ProductID,OrderDate) VALUES(2, 3,'2/1/2014'); -- no price

SELECT * FROM OrderLineItem;

SELECT * FROM OrderLineItem li LEFT OUTER JOIN  ProductPrice p on
p.ProductID=li.ProductID AND  OrderDate BETWEEN  startDate AND  EndDate;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a copy of the left table with added serial row numbers:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE OrderLineItem_serial AS
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS serial, * FROM OrderLineItem;
   ```

   Remark: This may work better for some tables formats (must be WITHOUT COMPRESSION):

   ```
   CONCAT(INPUT__FILE__NAME, BLOCK__OFFSET__INSIDE__FILE) AS serial
   ```
2. Do an inner join:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE OrderLineItem_inner AS
   SELECT * FROM OrderLineItem_serial li JOIN ProductPrice p
   on p.ProductID = li.ProductID WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN startDate AND EndDate;
   ```
3. Left join by serial:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM OrderLineItem_serial li
   LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderLineItem_inner i on li.serial = i.serial;
   ```

Comment: Sorry fro the delay- I have several issues: I am on Hive .10 - no windowed functions.   The second query used between in the join, which my version of hive does not support (my original problem). Thanks though!

Comment: 1. try using the concat...as serial instead of row_number...as serial, as mentioned in the remark below item 1
2. I changed the second query. since it is an inner join you can put the between condition in a where clause

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a WHERE clause that allows for NULL cases separately?

```
SELECT * FROM OrderLineItem li 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  ProductPrice p 
ON p.ProductID=li.ProductID 
WHERE ( StartDate IS NULL OR OrderDate BETWEEN startDate AND EndDate);
```

That should take care of it - if the left join matches it'll use the date logic, if it doesn't it'll keep the NULL values intact as a left join should.

Comment: what about if there is a match on product id but all the matches have start/end ranges outside of the order date, in that case you'd be filtering out the row, thus transforming a theoretical outer join into a query which can output less rows than OrderLineItem

Comment: Seconding what @fd8s0 noted, this is not a true left join and can result in less rows from the left table.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can avoid using a double join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OrderLineItem li 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (
  SELECT p.*
  FROM ProductPrice p
  JOIN OrderLineItem li 
  ON p.ProductID=li.ProductID 
  WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate ) p
ON p.ProductId = li.ProductID
WHERE StartDate IS NULL OR 
  OrderDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate;
```

This way if there is a match and StartDate is not null, there has to be a valid start/end date match.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It preserves a true left join by retaining rows where there is a match on product id but the order date is outside of the start and end date window (which should produce a null condition in the right table).  It's also more performant than the serial row number solution.

Answer (score -2):

Hive 0.10 supports cross joins, so you could handle all your "theta join" (non-equijoin) conditions in the WHERE clause.