# Emulating an interval join in hive

Tags: join, hive

I am using hive 0.13.

I have two tables:

1. data table. columns: id, time. 1E10 rows.
2. mymap table. columns: id, name, start_time, end_time. 1E6 rows.

For each row in the data table I want to get the name from the mymap table matching the id and the time interval. So I want to do a join like:

```
select data.id, time, name from data left outer join mymap on data.id = mymap.id and time>=start_time and time<end_time
```

It is known that for every row in data there are 0 or 1 matches in mymap.

The above query is not supported in hive as it is a non-equi-join. Moving the inequality conditions into a where filter does not work cause the join explodes before the filter is applied:

```
select data.id, time, name from data left outer join mymap on data.id = mymap.id where mymap.id is null or (time>=start_time and time<end_time)
```

(I am aware that the queries are not exactly equivalent due to cases where there is a match for id but no matching interval. This can be solved as I describe here: [Hive: work around for non equi left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112355/hive-work-around-for-non-equi-left-join/25472664#25472664))

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could perform your join and then query from that table.  I didn't test this code, but it would read something like

```
select id
    ,time
    ,name
from (
    select d.id
        ,d.time
        ,m.name
        ,m.start_time
        ,m.end_time
    from data as d LEFT OUTER JOIN mymap as m
        ON d.id = m.id
     ) x
where time>=start_time
        AND time<end_time
```

Comment: this is similar to the my second query. the problem is that the join explodes

Comment: My query is completely different.  You're trying to pass conditions in the where clause of your outer join, I am doing a nested query.  Did you try this code?  I created sample data and it works.

Comment: not sure why you think the second query is useful. anyway the problem is with big data

Comment: 1. a 2 x 10 billion table isn't that "big".  2. A query wouldn't work b/c you data is too "big", that is the point of MapReduce - scale.  Take a subset of your data and run mine against your's.  Mine is faster  I bet.

Comment: I think the issue here isn't the 10 billion rows - its that the mymap table might have very dense data for each id - If there are only 1000 ids, that 10 billion rows becomes 10 trillion!

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially get around this issue by flattening out the data structure in table2 and using a UDF to process the joined records.

```
select
   id,
   time,
   nameFinderUDF(b.name_list, time) as name
from
   data a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (
   select
      id,
      collect_set(array(name,cast(start_time as string),cast(end_time as string))) as name_list
   from
      mymap 
   group by
      id
   ) b
ON (a.id=b.id)
```

With a UDF that does something like:

```
public String evaluate(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> name_list,Long time) {
    for (int i;i<name_list.length;i++) {
       if (time >= Long.parseLong(name_list[i][1]) && time <= Long.parseLong(name_list[i][2])) {
           return name_list[i][0]
    return null;
}
```

This approach should make the merge 1 to 1, but it could create a fairly large data structure repeated many times.  It is still quite a bit more efficient than a straight join.