# Are NOT equal JOIN a standard use? T-SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have a table "Price"  that should be filtered according to a value stored in an another table "CutPrice" (meaning only prices inferior to the parameter stored should be displayed).

I experimented various way, and for a laugh I did the following:

```
SELECT     Location, Price, CutoffPrice
FROM            LocPrice INNER JOIN
CutPrice ON CutPrice.CutOffPrice < LocPrice.Price
```

Using the **inferior than** sign works perfectly, it's even faster than the Case statement I used in another version of the query.

I try googling for it, to see if it's standard, recommended, not recommended, even a bug , perhaps ?

I could not find anything. So I know, the question might be a bit broad for the site, but is this a standard use of JOINS or is there  anything  to be careful about when using this ? Particularly about T-SQL on SQL server 2005

Comment: It would really help if you told us what server you are using! It would also be polite if the 4 people who have already voted to close this had the courtesy to tell you why. So I will, this should really be asked on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Non-equi joins are a pretty standard part of SQL. See http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/oracle-sql-programming/basic-sql-join-semantics/ for example. Most of the major databases support non-equi joins, usually with both SQL 92 JOIN ON syntax and pre-SQL 92 WHERE syntax. However, if you have a particular database in mind searching for 'non-equi join `<db name>`' will usually find mention of it doesn't support them, e.g. [Hive: work around for non equi left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112355/hive-work-around-for-non-equi-left-join)

Comment: Thanks for naming the thing. My googling it was giving me no answers, as I did not have the exact term. Knowing what to look for is half of the work.